# How to Build Bare Git Repository on Local Server?

Tags: git, repository, git-push, git-pull

I have create a Git repository on my local server where we will commit & push our changes through eclipse.Further, we have connected with this local server git repository with our remote git repository (Adobe cloud git repository). I can successfully commit and push changes from my local machine to local server git repository. Now my this local server repository  stores data in pack files. Now before I push that local server branch(remote branch for my local machine) to our cloud git repository, we want to build that repository to make sure any code committed and push here is compiled and has no errors. How can I build that my bare git repository on local server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your local server, `git clone "remoteRepo"` and use that repository to build. You can also look into Continuous Integration tools like Jenkins to automate this process for you.

Comment: Can JenKins directly build bare repository or need to configure clone repository in JenKins ?

Comment: Sorry just saw this. Bare repositories cannot be built. They have to be cloned first. Jenkins can be set up to clone, though.

Comment: Yes. I managed to configure Bare Git repository in Jenkins, it itself clone it in its workspace and build it.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need to have a checkout of the repo somewhere.

The simplest way is : clone this bare repo, and use the clone.